# Env variables failed to load in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to export all the variables located in a `.conf`. So I followed this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79077/56901 answer.

`setenv.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

set -a
. "$DIR/settings.conf"
set +a
```

`settings.conf`

```
DB_ENV_USER="root"
DB_ENV_PASS="avi"
DB_ENV_NAME="s2s"
TEST_DB_ENV_NAME="testdb"
```

What I have tried is,

```
avi:~/project/_backend$
bash local/setenv.sh
avi:~/project/_backend$
echo $DB_ENV_USER

avi:~/project/_backend$
```

So it failed to show `$DB_ENV_USER` value `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works just fine. You just have to **source** it instead of **running** it:

```
. local/setenv.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

First you read the link

[What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i)

then you source the script

```
source local/setenv.sh
```