# Is is possible to export all variables obtained from sourcing a file?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Say I have a file called `variables.sh` that sets two variables.

```
foo=bar
bar=foo
```

If I `source` this file I can use these variables in the current shell, but if I want to use it in a second shell script I would have to export them instead, so the file would have to look like this:

```
export foo=bar
export bar=foo
```

It is possible to do some kind of `source` + `export` or do I have to change `variables.sh` so that there is `export` before every variable is set?

Comment: See also [How to export variables from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79064/315749)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> if I want to use it in a second shell script I would have to export them instead, so the file would have to look like this:

You could source the second file, or have it source `variables.sh`. There are multiple ways to do what you wask, such as doing an eval over the result of processing the file, but the cleanest way would be to use `set -a` of bash shell:

```
          -a      Automatically  mark  variables  and  functions which are
                  modified or created for export  to  the  environment  of
                  subsequent commands.
```

Thus, you can achieve your goal with:

```bsh
set -a
source variables.sh
```

As noted by [l0b0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3645/l0b0), you possibly want to `set +a` afterwards, so you don't continue autoexporting variables on subsequent shell code.

Comment: Nice, thanks! The reason I wouldn't source the file in the second script is because I want it to run over and over, so it would waste a lot of time just sourcing the same variables over and over when you could do it once.

Comment: You probably want to `set +a` after sourcing the file, to exporting *everything.*

Comment: @l0b0: good point, added into the answer